# Laravel Reset Password Notification does not get dispatched in test but does send an email

Tags: php, laravel, events, notifications, mocking

I am writing tests for my Laravel project. Right now I am testing the authentication code like login, logout, reset password and so on.

Sadly, my test is failing because there is no notification send. I have mocked the notifications but `assertSendTo` always fails with the reason `The expected [Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword] notification was not sent.`.

However, when actual requesting a reset password email (not in the test, as a normal user on my website) I indeed do get an reset password email. So, it is functional and working but not in my test. How can this be? The `.evn` is also correct, I have set my mail host to `mailtrap.io` and I also receive this email... This is the best proof I can give you.

Here is my test:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function a_not_logged_in_user_can_request_a_new_password()
    {
        Notification::fake();

        $email = Str::random() . "@gmail.com";
        $current_password = Str::random(16);
        $current_password_hash = Hash::make($current_password);

        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $current_password_hash
        ]);

        $response = $this->json('POST', route('password.email'), ['email' => $email]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertLocation(route('home'));
        
        //$this->expectsNotification($user, ResetPassword::class);
        Notification::assertSentTo($user, ResetPassword::class);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the test is not working or whats wrong with it?
Whats also very strange is the fact that the response code `200` is indicating that everything succeeded without any problem.

This is the error I get when executing the test with `assertSentTo`

```
1) Tests\Feature\Auth\LoggedIn\ForgotPassword\AuthTest::a_not_logged_in_user_can_request_a_new_password
The expected [Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword] notification was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.

MyWebsiteProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/NotificationFake.php:68
/MyWebsiteProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
MyWebsiteProject/tests/Feature/Auth/LoggedIn/ForgotPassword/AuthTest.php:35
```

And this is the error I get when executing it with `expectsNotification`

```
1) Tests\Feature\Auth\LoggedIn\ForgotPassword\AuthTest::a_logged_in_user_can_request_a_new_password
The following expected notification were not dispatched: [Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword]

MyWebsiteProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MocksApplicationServices.php:281
MyWebsiteProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:237
MyWebsiteProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:153
```

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: Put expects at the start of the test. It cannot expect a notification if it has already been sent.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please rephrase  it? @MHewison

Comment: there is no problem in your test, the structure is fully correct. double check your code. maybe you don't send notification and firing an event which send reset email. also you can debug your step during test with dd() to understand which step is currently run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inside your `User` model you are overwriting `sendPasswordResetNotification` using your custom notification class, then make sure inside your test file replace

```
Notification::assertSentTo($user, ResetPassword::class);
```

with

```
Notification::assertSentTo($user, YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expects does just that "expect that something is going to happen", in your case you are expecting it after the fact. The latter is the use case for an assertion. Something like the following is what you need.

```php
class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function a_not_logged_in_user_can_request_a_new_password()
    {
        $email = Str::random() . "@gmail.com";
        $current_password = Str::random(16);
        $current_password_hash = Hash::make($current_password);

        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $current_password_hash
        ]);

        // Expect that something is going to happen
        $this->expectsNotification($user, ResetPassword::class);
   
        $response = $this->json('POST', route('password.email'), ['email' => $email]);

        // Assertion that something has happened
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertLocation(route('home'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry,  I do get the exact same error as in my test!

Comment: Sorry, remove the Notification::fake(); i have edited to reflect

Comment: Nope, not working for me.. I get the exact same error `The following expected notification were not dispatched: [Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword]`

Comment: So in that case, it is likely that, the ResetPassword notification is not being dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

My app was initially created in L5 when the default `User.php` fully qualified class name was
`App\User.php` but, according to L8 new pattern, I've duplicated it (to avoid refactoring.... my fault) to `App\Models\User.php`.

https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1296556354593792000

This partial misalignment, though, left some of my tests behind, expecially the ones involving fake-notifications in which `UserFactory` kept dispatching (via `NotificationFake.php`) to `App\User.php` instead of `App\Models\User.php` and determining the `assertSentTo` to fail.

***TLDR***
make sure that `config/auth.php` (param `providers.users.model`)  and `UserFactory.php` rely on the same model.

Answer (score -1):

In case non of the above solutions works for you like in my case, try adding this line at the top of your test function;

```php
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

This will give you a good error message as to where the problem might be coming from. In my case, I was using the wrong route.

Comment: Finally, this is the only solution that has worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue when I customised the authentication system. I have created a custom notification and used it instead of Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword; and it worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34771748)

Comment: @RamChander can you elaborate? why do you think this is [not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11107541)?